# What is the difference between the standard topology and discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Today I had a thought about how we construct the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we first define the Euclidean 2-norm metric on it, and define the open ball centered at a point $x$ as the set of points $y$ satisfying the relation $d(x,y)<r$. The open sets $U$ of the topology are those set for when $ x \in U$ then there is a ball containing which $x$  contained in $U$.

But, couldn't we just get the same set topology by considering all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be open? Why go through this procedure of getting a metric first, then creating balls and then defining a topology using these balls?

Comment: I think you are confusing the trivial topology and the discrete topology. Also in your comment, $T$ I think you mean $\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}....\} $ @Buraian

Comment: Well yes, definition wise they are different but wouldn't any open set in the standard topology be open also in the discrete topology @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: The goal of defining a topology on a set isn't to get as much openness as possible, it's to have openness be a somehow useful/interesting notion. Making all sets open usually doesn't result in openness being interesting (although sometimes the discrete topology is worth considering).

Comment: "wouldn't any open set in the standard topology be open also in the discrete topology" Yes, but the converse would not be true. No (nonempty) finite set is open in the usual topology, for example.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a (non empty) finite set, do you mean to consider  collection of individua lpoints on the real line ? @NoahSchweber

Comment: @Buraian Yes.  A non-empty finite set is a set like $\{1,2,3\}$, which is not empty, and has only a finite number of elements.  Such sets are not open in the usual topology, but *are* open in the discrete topology.

Comment: I guess that's the answer for the question then. Thanks @NoahSchweber If you post that as answer to this post, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer:*

The goal of defining a topology on a set isn't to get as much openness as possible (and in particular don't in any way conflate "open" and "good"). Instead, it's to have openness be a somehow useful/interesting notion. Making all sets open usually doesn't result in openness being interesting (although sometimes the discrete topology is worth considering).

Relatedly, you ask

> "wouldn't any open set in the standard topology be open also in the discrete topology"

This is indeed the case, but the converse would not be true. No (nonempty) finite set is open in the usual topology, for example - e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^1$, the set $\{17\}$ is open in the discrete topology but not open in the usual topology.

Comment: The first paragraph, I think it is somehow related to the main problems I have in understanding topology, do you have any suggestions on how I can understand more of the question "why we choose the level of openess that we do in topology?"

Comment: We already have an analytic definition of continuous functions, based on the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. The open subsets of, say, $\mathbb R^1$ were designed so that the open set definition of continuity and the analytic definition of continuity are equivalent. So if you read that proof of equivalence (in the metric spaces chapter of any topology book), you'll get a better feel for why openness in $\mathbb R$ is defined the way it is.